# Access nested dictionary without loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have a nested dictionary
`mydict={'a1':{'b1':1}, 'a2':2}`
and a list of indexes `index = ['a1', 'b1']` leading to an inner value, is there a pythonic / one-liner way to get that value, i.e. without resorting to a verbose loop like:

```
d = mydict
for idx in index:
    d = d[idx]
print(d)
```

Comment: `mydict[index[0]][index[1]]` seems to be what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> mydict = {'a1':{'b1':1}, 'a2':2}
>>> keys = ['a1', 'b1']
>>> reduce(dict.get, keys, mydict)
1
```

`dict.get` is a function that takes two arguments, the `dict` and a key (and another optional argument not relevant here). `mydict` is used as the initial value.

In case you ever need the intermediary results, use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate([mydict] + keys, dict.get))
[{'a1': {'b1': 1}, 'a2': 2}, {'b1': 1}, 1]
```

Unfortunately, the function does not take an optional `initializer` argument, so we are prepending `mydict` to `keys`.